# How to write a procedure in snowflake to update a column from Source table to Target table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The required format for the Problem is:

```
update t
set boost_combo = 'oxaliplatin'
from source_product t
where category like '%eloxa%'
```

This one needs to be written in procedure and it should run in a loop.
The Source table name is PRODUCT_SOURCE. AND ANOTHER TABLE NAME IS MDM_REF_SEGMENTATION.

I am trying to create a procedure for:

```
update t
set boost_combo = 'oxaliplatin'
from source_product t
where category like '%eloxa%'
```

Can you guide me how to create it.

I have one Procedure created need to implement the above requirement inside the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_CHC_D_CATEGORIZING_MULTIPLE_INSERT_SCRIPT"("COLUMN_OPERATOR" ARRAY, "KEY_COLUMNS" ARRAY)
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS 
$$
        /* DELETING DATA FROM INTERMEDIATE_DS_REF_CATEGORY*/
        var sql_command_delete="delete from DF_CHC_DEV.PSA_MARKET_SALES.INTERMEDIATE_DS_REF_CATEGORY";

   
    /* EXECUTING THE SQL COMMAND*/
    var rs_delete = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command_delete});  

    /* A INSERT AND SELECT SYNTAX is implemented in SCRIPT_FRAME1 to load data into INTERMEDIATE_DS_REF_CATEGORY from MDM_MARKET_DEFINITION and MDM_MARKET.*/
    let SCRIPT_FRAME1 ="INSERT INTO DF_CHC_DEV.PSA_MARKET_SALES.INTERMEDIATE_DS_REF_CATEGORY(MDM_MARKET_DEFINITION_ID,MARKET_ID,INCLUSION_FLAG,MARKET_DEFINITION_NAME,WHERE_CONDITION) SELECT MDM_MARKET_DEFINITION_ID,MARKET_ID,INCLUSION_FLAG, MARKET_DEFINITION_NAME, 'WHERE '||";
    
    /* SCRIPT_FRAME2 HAS select query*/
    let SCRIPT_FRAME2 = " FROM (SELECT MDM_MARKET_DEFINITION_ID,MARKET_ID,INCLUSION_FLAG, MARKET_DEFINITION_NAME,";
    
    /* In SCRIPT_FRAME3, there is a list of the source tables and the join conditions*/
    let SCRIPT_FRAME3=" FROM DF_CHC_DEV.PSA_MARKET_SALES.MDM_MARKET_DEFINITION AS A JOIN DF_CHC_DEV.PSA_MARKET_SALES.MDM_MARKET AS B ON A.MARKET_DEFINITION_NAME = B.MARKET_LEVEL_0 WHERE A.MARKET_DEFINITION_NAME NOT IN ('PV') AND COALESCE(A.CHANNEL_NAME, 'FF') NOT LIKE '%ACTUALS%' ORDER BY MDM_MARKET_DEFINITION_ID ASC);";
    
    /* The KEY_COLUMNS1 variable is creating a dynamic SQL script that depends on the input values of key_columns*/
    let KEY_COLUMNS1=KEY_COLUMNS.map((e,i)=>`ifnull(${KEY_COLUMNS[i]}_, '1=1')`)
    
    /* The COLUMN_OPERATOR variable dynamically generates a SQL script that aligns with the business requirements, using the SQL query within the COLUMN_OPERATOR*/
    COLUMN_OPERATOR=COLUMN_OPERATOR.map((elem,i)=>`CASE WHEN A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} = '=' THEN 'IN' WHEN A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} = '<>' THEN 'NOT IN' WHEN A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} = 'START WITH' OR A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} = 'END WITH'THEN 'LIKE ANY' WHEN A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} = 'LIKE' OR A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} = 'NOT LIKE' THEN 'LIKE ANY' ELSE A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} END AS ${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]}_,CASE WHEN A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} = '=' OR A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} = '<>' THEN '${KEY_COLUMNS[i]} '||${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]}_||' (\\''||REPLACE(REPLACE(${KEY_COLUMNS[i]},'''',''''''),';','\\',\\'')||'\\')' WHEN A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} ='LIKE' THEN '${KEY_COLUMNS[i]} '||${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]}_||' (\\'%'||REPLACE(REPLACE(${KEY_COLUMNS[i]},'''',''''''),';','%\\',\\'%')||'%\\')' WHEN  A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} ='NOT LIKE' THEN 'NOT (${KEY_COLUMNS[i]} '||${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]}_||' (\\'%'||REPLACE(REPLACE(${KEY_COLUMNS[i]},'''',''''''),';','%\\',\\'%')||'%\\'))' WHEN A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} ='START WITH' THEN '${KEY_COLUMNS[i]} '||${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]}_||' (\\''||REPLACE(REPLACE(${KEY_COLUMNS[i]},'''',''''''),';','%\\',\\'')||'%\\')' WHEN A.${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]} ='END WITH' THEN '${KEY_COLUMNS[i]} '||${COLUMN_OPERATOR[i]}_||' (\\''||REPLACE(REPLACE(${KEY_COLUMNS[i]},'''',''''''),';','\\',\\'%')||'%\\')' ELSE ${KEY_COLUMNS[i]} END AS ${KEY_COLUMNS[i]}_`)

    /* SCRIPT_FRAME1, SCRIPT_FRAME2,SCRIPT_FRAME3 and KEY_COLUMNS1 are variables being added in sql_command_final_where_condition  */
    let sql_command_final_where_condition=SCRIPT_FRAME1+KEY_COLUMNS1.join('||\' and \'||')+SCRIPT_FRAME2+COLUMN_OPERATOR.join(',')+SCRIPT_FRAME3
    
    /* executing the sql command*/
    var rs_1 = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command_final_where_condition});

    /* Selecting all data from INTERMEDIATE_DS_REF_CATEGORY and storing it into array_of_rows*/

    var sql_command ="SELECT * FROM DF_CHC_DEV.PSA_MARKET_SALES.INTERMEDIATE_DS_REF_CATEGORY order by MDM_MARKET_DEFINITION_ID";
                        
                var rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command});
                var json_obj = {};
                var array_of_rows = [];
                while (rs.next())  {
                            var json_object = {};
                            json_object["MDM_MARKET_DEFINITION_ID"]=rs.getColumnValue(1);
                            json_object["MARKET_ID"]=rs.getColumnValue(2);
                            json_object["INCLUSION_FLAG"]=rs.getColumnValue(3);
                            json_object["MARKET_DEFINITION_NAME"]=rs.getColumnValue(4);
                            json_object["WHERE_CONDITION"]=rs.getColumnValue(5);                
                            array_of_rows.push(json_object);    
                        }

    /* By using the loop command, all rules data is inserted into the final MDM_MARKET_FACT table*/
                
            for(var m = 0 ; m < array_of_rows.length; m++){
            
                let final_insert_script=`INSERT INTO DF_CHC_DEV.PSA_MARKET_SALES.MDM_MARKET_FACT(SOURCE_PRODUCT_ID, MARKET_ID, MARKET_LEVEL_0) select SP.SOURCE_PRODUCT_ID,${array_of_rows[m].MARKET_ID},\'${array_of_rows[m].MARKET_DEFINITION_NAME}\' from DF_CHC_DEV.PSA_MARKET_SALES.SOURCE_PRODUCT AS SP JOIN DF_CHC_DEV.PSA_MARKET_SALES.PANEL AS PL ON SP.PANEL_ID  = PL.PANEL_ID  ${array_of_rows[m].WHERE_CONDITION}`;
    
    /* executing the sql command*/
                var rs_final = snowflake.execute({sqlText: final_insert_script});
                            
    }   

            return "INSERTING DATA IS SUCCESSFULL";

    $$              
;


CALL SP_CHC_D_CATEGORIZING_MULTIPLE_INSERT_SCRIPT (ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('COUNTRY_NAME_OPERATOR','PANEL_NAME_OPERATOR','CHANNEL_NAME_OPERATOR','CLASS_TYPE_OPERATOR','ATC4_OPERATOR','PRODUCT_LOCAL_OPERATOR','PRODUCT_OPERATOR','MANUFACTURER_OPERATOR','CORPORATION_LOCAL_OPERATOR','CORPORATION_OPERATOR','MOLECULE_LIST_LOCAL_OPERATOR','MOLECULE_LIST_OPERATOR','PACK_LOCAL_OPERATOR','PACK_OPERATOR','NFC123_LOCAL_OPERATOR','NFC123_OPERATOR','CHC_CLASS_OPERATOR','CHC_FORM_OPERATOR','RX_OPERATOR'),ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('COUNTRY_NAME','PANEL_NAME','CHANNEL_NAME','CLASS_TYPE','ATC4','PRODUCT_LOCAL','PRODUCT','MANUFACTURER','CORPORATION_LOCAL','CORPORATION','MOLECULE_LIST_LOCAL','MOLECULE_LIST','PACK_LOCAL','PACK','NFC123_LOCAL','NFC123','CHC_CLASS','CHC_FORM','RX_STATUS'));
```

Comment: Your SP has a very similar logic. So it shouldn't be a problem to modify it and add that update. Which part are you struggle?

Comment: The update needs to be done for different table. we have one source table to that we need to update the column and the results should be dynamically run in the procedure.